# Axis and allies 1942 edition

Tags: axis-and-allies

Can a lone transport pass through an enemy submarine occupied sea zone with nothing happening or would it be considered a naval attack?

Answer (score 1):

## Sea units can safely enter or pass through territories occupied by enemy submarines only

As stated in its profile on page 30 of the rule book, a submarine has the characteristic *"Does Not Block Enemy Movement"* which in short *allows enemy ships to ignore their presence*. No combat is triggered if the player entering or passing through  the zone does not choose so.

Be aware that this has nothing to do with transports specifically, but is a characteristic of submarines and applies to all sea units.

Full text of the characteristic for reference:

> The “stealth” ability of submarines also allows enemy ships to ignore their presence. Any sea zone that contains only enemy submarines does not stop the movement of a sea unit. Sea units ending their combat movement in a sea zone containing only enemy submarines may choose to attack them or not. Sea units can also end their noncombat movement in a sea zone containing only enemy submarines.